# Azure Cosmos DB Implementation Failure

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb, portal

I'm having a problem whenever I try to create a new Cosmos DB database through Azure Portal. I'm using a free subscription so I do not have access to CosmosDB support.

Basically, all values seem to be valid but after creation everything fails. I'm doing the following:

1. Input a unique ID with no spaces or uppercases or symbols.
2. Chose "Azure Table" as API type.
3. Use my "Free Trial" subscription.
4. Create a new resource group (again with no spaces or uppercases of symbols).
5. Choose a server in either "South UK" and "North Europe" (tried both on different tries).

**Whenever I click finish, after some seconds, I get the following message:**

> Invalid capability EnableTable. ActivityId: ... 
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.10.106.1 (Code: BadRequest)

**Error Message:**

> {
>    "code": "BadRequest", 
>  "message": "Invalid capability
>   EnableTable.\r\nActivityId: 9cb0e2eb-3b62-4bda-a0f9-e3945eb8148b,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.19.106.1" 
> }

I also tried Edge and Chrome and neither work. I find funny that Microsoft says that we can try Azure's CosmosDB for free but in fact we can't because creation fails and they offer no support for free.

Comment: Does it work using Document DB as API ?

Comment: You need to use the below url to try Cosmos DB free. I just created one DB for free. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cosmosdb/

Comment: This is working for MongoDB API for example. Haven't tested all of them but at least Mongo works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Not really sure if this can be considered an answer, but my problem has solved itself somehow. Apparently the solution is to keep trying multiple times till it works.

If it helps the only different thing I did this time was:

1. Create first an Azure Cosmos MongoDB, including creating a new resource group
2. Create now the Azure Table DB using the existing resource group used by Mongo DB.
3. It worked.

Not sure if it was this or and Azure error or subscription issue, since I created my account today, so It could not be properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below url and select the required service to try Cosmos DB free. 
I just created one Cosmos SQL DB for free. [image]

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cosmosdb/